# Android LocationManager class is not returning correct latitude/longitude

Tags: android, android-mapview, locationmanager

I created a program that displays a mapView, with the location of the phone, and the ability to send this location (latitude, longitude) through email. (to add some places to a database).

I'm using the LocationManager class and getLatitude / getLongitude methods to get the phone's location. My code looks like this:

```
double MyLongitude  = 0;
double MyLatitude   = 0;
Location location   = null;

LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 35000, 10, new ShowLocation()); 

location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

MyLatitude  = location.getLatitude();
MyLongitude = location.getLongitude();
```

When test my application on the emulator, everything is OK: mapView displays the location I fixed (using telnet and geo fix command), and I can send the location through email. I get the same result on the phone of a friend; everything seems to work OK.

The problem is on my phone. I can display my location on the mapView (the little blue circle), but when I try to send my location through email, the Latitude and Longitude were both set to 0.

Here is the code to display my location on the mapView:

```
MyLocationOverlay myLocation = new MyLocationOverlay(this, mapView);
myLocation.enableMyLocation();
```

I don't understand why my location appears to work when displayed, but I can't get the correct latitude and longitude, while it seems to work on emulator and my friend's phone.

Is this due to missing code or something like that? Is this a problem with my phone? I checked the permissions, and I already have the needed ones:

```
android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION
```

I also tried to test with LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER instead of LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, but got the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override onLoationChanged(Location l) on your MyLocationOverlay, which will get called whenever the overlay gets a new location to draw your position, instead of requesting location updates and getLastKnownLocation.

I am guessing that getLastKnownLocation is returning 0, 0 because there hasn't been a location fix yet.

Comment: The class where the mapView is display has LocationListener implemented, so i have "OnLocationChanged" method implemented. In there, i just use getLatitude and getLongitude methods from LocationManager.

Comment: Is there another method to fix location on my phone ?

Comment: If you get longitude and latitude of the location in OnLocationChanged, it is also 0,0?

Comment: Hi,
Finally it seems to work.
The problem was my fault :
I had a class (_DisplayMap_), where the mapview is displayed, that implement **LocationListener**.
So i used the methods **onLocationChanged** from this class.
But the problem was my call of the method **requestLocationUpdates** :
`lm.requestLocationUpdates(provider,35000, 10,new ShowLocation());`

Comment: I used an other class (_ShowLocation_) that implement **LocationListener**, and i didn't use it methods. 
I changed my code, and used **onLocationChanged** method from this class, and now it seems to work. 

I don't know why it worked before on emulator and my friend's phone, but nevermind, now it's ok ;)

Many thanks for gave me this tip ;)